# NSIS FileRead dont work with Variables

Tags: nsis

I have minor problem in my NSIS-Script,
im calling this Function:

```
Function ReadAllDesc 
 Var /global j
 ${foreach} $j 0 $secCount + 1
   SectionGetText $h $4
   ${StrContains} $5 "++" $4
   ${ifnot} $5 == ""
     StrCpy $5 $4 "" 2
   ${else}
     StrCpy $5 $4
   ${endif}
   !insertmacro DESC_READ $4 $lang $5
 ${next}
FunctionEnd
```

in descriptionInit Function
The Macro that i insert is the following:

```
!macro DESC_READ addonText lang addonVar
  FileOpen $6 "$TEMP\addonInstallerPreFolder\5.1\${addonText}_${lang}.txt" r
  ${if} ${addonText} == proFile
    FileRead $6 $proFileDesc
  ${else}
    ${if} ${addonText} == "ExtensionsFrame"
      FileRead $6 $extensions
    ${else}
      FileRead $6 $${addonVar}
    ${endIf}
  ${endIf}
  FileClose $6
!macroend
```

at compile time i get an error in the macroline FileRead $6 $${addonVar} that the syntax is false. But when i  change the macro call to a fix example like:

```
!insertmacro DESC_READ "ExtensionsFrame" $lang "extensions"
```

it works correctly. I need this because of i´m reading an Variable count on descriptions and don´t want to write fix code in this case.

Comment: Why do you have a double dollar there? Why not `${addonVar}`?

Comment: The double $ is for the name of the global Variable where is filled in ${addonVar}. And then the next $ is for the variable call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but definitely try with just on dollar. It should work.

Comment: It should work in this way: $${addonVar} =$ext. Ext is the value of addonVar. Then the file read writes into $ext witch is a global variable. But when I insert variables in the call of my macro. Then it don't with fix values like ext it do work.